# Linearity of Differential Operators: Is it valid to say that $\frac{d}{dy} |g'(y)| = |g''(y)|$?

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

Since the differential operator is linear, is it valid to say that $\dfrac{d}{dy} |g'(y)| = |g''(y)|$?

I would appreciate it if someone would please clarify this.

Comment: Chain rule. Look at $d|x|/dx$ when $x>0$ and when $x<0$ and apply it accordingly. Note that $|\cdot|$ isn't linear in general.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ahh, I thought this might be the case. So since it requires the chain rule, then it must be dependent on the (definition of the) norm in question, so it (what I wrote in the post) cannot be valid. Thanks for the quick clarification!

Comment: @ThePointer This is not linearity.

Comment: @OliverJones You’re right. I should have been more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example.  $g(x) = \sin x$.  Then $g'(x) = \cos x$, $g''(x) = -\sin x$.  Here are graphs,

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}|g'(x)|$
[image]

$|g''(x)|$
[image]
Are they the same?